# Copying Data from One Sheet to Another if Criteria is Met

Tags: microsoft-excel

My goal is to total the data in sheet 1 (Master Data) Column "E" based on the criteria (names) in column "J" to populate in sheet 2 (User Index) column "J" as long as it matches the name in column "B" of sheet 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done with a simple Sumif function.

In Sheet 2, use something along these lines, starting in row 2 and copy down.

```
=sumif('Master Data'!J:J,B2,'Master Data'!E:E)
```

Adjust ranges to suit your scenario.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! Is there a known way to have the data populated (based on the formula provided) in sheet 2 change based on the filtered data in sheet one?? For instance if i wanted to filter the information to specific dates on sheet 1 would it change the total labor for the range of dates provided?

Comment: You may want to look into Pivot Tables. No formulas and powerful filtering with a few clicks.